# Parsing specific elements in R

Tags: r, parsing

```
V21.X1  V21.X2
A       02:01:03
A       02:01:04
A       03:01:05
A       03:01:04
```

Using `which` I took a vector or column from a data frame and split it into two new columns (as shown above), but I want to filter the rows containing 02:01. I tried to split `V21.X1` separately again using `which`, but R does not treat `V21.X2` as an individual column but a part of `X1` and `X2` combined or `V21`.

I want to store this output in another variable:

```
V21.X1  V21.X2   
A       02:01:03
A       02:01:04
```

Comment: Try `subset(df1, grepl("^02:01", V21.X2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a regex to match the pattern for filtering the rows

```
subset(df1, grepl("^02:01", V21.X2))
#   V21.X1   V21.X2
#1      A 02:01:03
#2      A 02:01:04
```

Or extract with `substr` and then do a `==`

```
subset(df1, substr(V21.X2, 1, 5)=='02:01')
#  V21.X1   V21.X2
#1      A 02:01:03
#2      A 02:01:04
```

---

If the dataset is a `matrix` column, there is only a sngle column i.e. 'V21' which store the `matrix` with two columns 'X1' and 'X2'

```
m1 <- cbind(X1 = "A", X2 = c("02:01:03", "02:01:04", "03:01:05", "03:01:04"))
df1 <- data.frame(V21 = rep(NA, 4))
df1$V21 <- m1
subset(df1,  grepl("^02:01", V21.X2))
```

> Error in grepl("^02:01", V21.X2) : object 'V21.X2' not found

A solution would be to convert the columns to normal columns in the `data.frame` and do the `subset`

```
df2 <- do.call(data.frame, df1)
subset(df2, grepl("^02:01", V21.X2))
#   V21.X1   V21.X2
#1      A 02:01:03
#2      A 02:01:04
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V21.X1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), V21.X2 = c("02:01:03", 
 "02:01:04", "03:01:05", "03:01:04")), .Names = c("V21.X1", "V21.X2"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I tried that but it still says object V21.X2 not found

Comment: @nathan Pleae check the `str` of the dataset.  I think it is a `matrix` with a single column

Comment: Thank you that worked now and you were right it was a matrix!